# reset master in percona xtradb cluster

Tags: mysql, database-replication, galera, gtid, percona-xtradb-cluster

I have two pxc clusters each consisting of 3 mysql servers.
 PXC1(node1,node2,node3) has db1 and db2, and PXC2(node4,node5,node6) has db2 and db3. 
I've setup a gtid based replication between pxc1(node1) and pxc2(node3).

Now the replication failed as master(pxc1) has purged gtids that needed for pxc2. I've gone through many blogs and forums. Everyone suggested to change the gtid_purged value after running the command reset master in slave.

But, in pxc cluster reset master is not allowed. Is there any solution to fix the replication.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to stop the Galera replication on the cluster 2 and then perform  reset master. The simplest way is stop all MySQL nodes on the cluster 2 except for the slave node and then comment out the wsrep_provider variable in your my.cnf or Galera related config file and restart the slave node. Then you should be able to run reset master. Once that's all done then start other nodes one by one.